# Having multiple sass directories for includes in Jekyll site for GitHub Pages?

Tags: sass, jekyll, github-pages

I use my Jekyll site (hosted on GitHub Pages) to do a lot of demos and the like. To avoid having to split up where those demo files live I'd really like to be able to include a directory inside the demo folder that I can use to do Sass includes (rather than building longer single files).

In other words:

`/css` should allow Sass includes from that folder or a sub-folder (which it does currently).

`/demos/project-1/css` should allow Sass includes from within that folder, or a sub folder (it doesn't currently).

I haven't figured out how to make this behave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the directories that you need to process with *sass* in `_config.yml`, for example if you have sass files in `another_path` then use:

```
sass:
    load_paths:
        - _sass
        - another_path
```

Sass will process the files located in `_sass` and `another_path`.